# if __name__ == main PHP to protect my code

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am somehow a noobie in PHP and I want to learn. I am making a proyect, in which I use `require('parts/header.php')` statements to include functions and templates. My pages look like this:

```
<?php 
include('core/checklogin.php');
//This will check if the user is logged in and can see this page or not
include('parts/top.php');
//This loads the <head> tags and the header, including the navbar
?>

<section id="mainArea">
    <h1>Hello <?php echo getUserNickname()?></h1>
    <p>Some stuff</p>
</section>

<?php 
include('parts/bottom.php');
//This loads the <head> tags and the header, including the navbar
?>
```

The problem is if someone enters myproyect.com/parts/top.php he would see the top part, and that file is going to be executed. I don't want that. I was thinking doing some stuff in a .htaccess file like:

```
 #.htaccess inside parts directory
 dont_serve_anything_inside_this_directory_and_return_forbidden();
```

But I don't know how without affecting the server side code.
Another alternative is to use the equivalent of `if __name__ == 'main':`  of python, and do like:

```
 //parts/top.php
 if(__name__ == 'main'){
     header('Location: /index.php');
     exit();
 }
```

What could I do?

Comment: move top.php  outside the web root, then there is no access via the web-server

Comment: Your answer is a good solution, thank you. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create file `.htaccess` inside your so-called *protected from the outside direct access* folder and put the following content there:

```
Deny from all
```

This will prevent users from being able to access your files using `http://example.com/parts/bottom.php`

Just add `.htacccess` to `parts` folder.